# TinyMCE: Don't display h1 on "styleselect" on toolbar

Tags: tinymce

I am using Tinymce as editor for my blog. I don't use H1 at all to write my blog (because it's already predefined as static element), so I want to remove h1 from toolbar "styleselect (format) > headings". Is it possible?

```
inymce.init({
    selector: '.content_textarea',
    menubar: false,     
    toolbar: 'undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | numlist bullist | link image | codesample source code | emoticons' 
});
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

If you are NOT using 'toolbar':

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: 'textarea',  // change this value according to your html
    // Define your own styles
    style_formats: [
    {title: 'Heading 2', format: 'h2'},
    {title: 'Heading 3', format: 'h3'},
    {title: 'Heading 4', format: 'h4'},
    {title: 'Heading 5', format: 'h5'},
    {title: 'Heading 6', format: 'h6'},
    {title: 'Normal', block: 'div'}
    ],
});
```

If you are using 'toolbar':

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: 'textarea',  // change this value according to your html
  toolbar: 'undo redo | formatselect | bold italic | link image',
  // Define your own styles
  block_formats: 'Paragraph=p; Heading 2=h2; Heading 3=h3; Heading 4=h4; Heading 5=h5; Heading 6=h6'
});
```

[Source](https://community.tiny.cloud/communityQuestion?com.salesforce.visualforce.ViewStateCSRF=VmpFPSxNakF5TUMwd05TMHlORlF5TVRvek1Eb3hNUzQ0TkRoYSxVM0NJWDNCX2R1amJabHBhaWtHQ1BSLFkyVTNabUl4&com.salesforce.visualforce.ViewStateVersion=202005202226300944&id=90661000000QcyYAAS&j_id0%3Aj_id1%3Aj_id178=j_id0%3Aj_id1%3Aj_id178&j_id0%3Aj_id1%3Aj_id178%3Abody=%3Cp%3ETo+remove+%27h1%27+or+any+unwanted+format+if+using+toolbar+use+the+option+%27block_formats%27+as+explained+in+the+docs+%3Ca+href%3D%22https%3A%2F%2Fwww.tiny.cloud%2Fdocs%2Fconfigure%2Feditor-appearance%2F%23block_formats%22%3Ehttps%3A%2F%2Fwww.tiny.cloud%2Fdocs%2Fconfigure%2Feditor-appearance%2F%23block_formats%3C%2Fa%3E%3C%2Fp%3E%0D%0A%3Cpre+class%3D%22language-javascript%22%3Etinymce.init%28%7B%0D%0A++selector%3A+%27textarea%27%2C++%2F%2F+change+this+value+according+to+your+html%0D%0A++block_formats%3A+%27Paragraph%3Dp%3BHeader+2%3Dh2%3BHeader+3%3Dh3%27%0D%0A%7D%29%3B%3C%2Fpre%3E&j_id0%3Aj_id1%3Aj_id178%3Aj_id180=Save+Answer%3Fid%3D90661000000QcyYAAS)

Answer (score 0):

In my case for TinyMCE v.4 the following helped to change 'format' select-box:

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: 'textarea',
    // Define your own styles
    theme_advanced_blockformats : "p,address,pre,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6",
});
```

`style_formats` parameter is changing 'style' select-box if you configured it to include `h1` as well.